# tidy predictions and confusion matrix with glmnet

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet

Consider this example:

```
library(quanteda)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(dplyr)

dtrain <- data_frame(text = c("Chinese Beijing Chinese",
                              "Chinese Chinese Shanghai",
                              "Chinese Macao",
                              "Tokyo Japan Chinese"),
                     doc_id = 1:4,
                     class = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "N"))

# now we make the dataframe bigger 
dtrain <- purrr::map_df(seq_len(100), function(x) dtrain)
```

Lets create a sparse document-term-matrix and run some `glmnet`

```
> dtrain <- dtrain %>% mutate(class = as.factor(class))
> mycorpus <- corpus(dtrain,  text_field = 'text')
> trainingdf <- dfm(mycorpus)
> trainingdf
Document-feature matrix of: 400 documents, 6 features (62.5% sparse).
```

And now we finally turn to the lasso model

```
mymodel <- cv.glmnet(x = trainingdf, y =dtrain$class, 
                     type.measure ='class',
                     nfolds = 3,
                     alpha = 1,
                     parallel = FALSE,
                     family = 'binomial')
```

I have two simple questions.

How can I add the predictions to the original `dtrain` data? Indeed, the mere output of

```
mypred <- predict.cv.glmnet(mymodel, newx = trainingdf, 
                         s = 'lambda.min', type = 'class')
```

looks HORRIBLY NOT TIDY:

```
> mypred
    1  
1   "Y"
2   "Y"
3   "Y"
```

How can I use `caret::confusionMatrix` in this setting? Just using the following creates an error:

```
confusion <- caret::confusionMatrix(data =mypred, 
+                                     reference = dtrain$class)
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

Thanks!

Comment: the target class should have the same number of levels in both train and test, can you check with `levels(my_train$class)` and `levels(my_test$class)` ?

Comment: In every model the target variable needs to be a `factor`. You can force it with `as.factor(my_train$my_target)`. It will automatically detect the correct levels

Comment: As RLave mentioned, your `mypred` is a `matrix` and is `character` class. you need `caret::confusionMatrix(data =as.factor(mypred), reference = dtrain$class)`

Comment: thanks @akrun, and do you know how to  add the predictions to the original dataframe?

Comment: `dtrain %>% mutate(pred = factor(as.vector(mypred)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every classification model the class for your target variable needs to be `factor`.

For example:

`my_data` is the dataset you train the model on, and `my_target` is the predictor.

Note that `as.factor(my_data$my_target)` will automatically find the correct `levels` for you.

By this I mean that you won't need to specify the `levels` by hand, but R will do it for you.

See here the difference when we call `target`:

```
target <- c("y", "n", "y", "n")
target
#[1] "y" "n" "y" "n" # this is a simple char
as.factor(target)
# [1] y n y n
# Levels: n y # this is a correct format, a factor with levels
```

This is important because even if your predictions (or test data) will show only one of the two classes in the `target`, the model will know that the actual `levels` can be more.

You can of course set them:

```
my_pred <- factor(mypred, levels = c("Y", "N"))
```

To add them in the data, you can use

```
my_data$newpred <- my_pred
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% mutate(newpred = my_pred)
```

Comment: thanks but what do you mean by `as.factor(my_data$my_target)` will find the correct labels for me? what is `my_data` in my example?